# Can't install Azure Module in PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell

When installing the Azure module:

```
PS> Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
```

I get this error:

> PackageManagement\Install-Package : Could not find a part of the path
> 'C:\Users\MB\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Az.Accounts\1.7.1'.
> At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1809 char:21

- ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
- ```
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exce
    ption
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand,Micro
    soft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage

Comment: You need to provide what steps you have done and which document you followed.

Comment: This is Microsoft's documentation on how to install Azure for Powershell. It just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

According to Microsoft, you can also install the MSI directly since their Powershell module installer is broken at the moment.

According to the documentation:
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps-msi)

Navigate to the Azure Github release page https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases
Scroll down until you find the latest Assets chevron that contains an Az-Cmdlets-x.x.x-x64.msi file.
Download and install the MSI.
Relaunch Powershell and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option here is to start from scratch:

1. Go to 'C:\Users\MB\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\' and remove all folders starting with "Az"
2. Launch PS as admin and update NuGet to latest version:

   ```
   Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force -Scope AllUsers
   ```
3. In the same window install latest version of PackageProvider:

   ```
   Install-Module -Name PackageManagement -Scope AllUsers -Force -AllowClobber
   ```
4. In the same window install latest version of PowerShellGet

   ```
   Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Scope AllUsers -Force -AllowClobber
   ```
5. Install Azure

   ```
   Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Force -Allowclobber
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix the issue.